# How can I teach `git-rerere` about the resolutions in an existing merge commit, with the least manual intervention

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rerere

[`git-rerere`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) is the exact solution to a problem I have ... except that the merges that need to be "learnt" have already been performed and are non-trivial to repeat.

How can I "teach" `rerere` about those commits with the minimum manual intervention.

Supposing that existing, but conflicting, branches `A` and `B` were merged together to form commit `C` with resolved conflicts.
Then I was hoping to do:

- `git checkout A`
- `git merge B`

  - merge pauses when conflicts observed.
- `git reset --soft C`

  - working files are now in the desired final state - i.e. the conflicts were "resolved".
- `git merge --continue`

  - `rerere` sees the updated files as the appropriate resolution, and "learns" this resolution.

But the `reset` step doesn't work :(

- A `--soft` reset isn't permitted during a merge.
- A `--mixed` reset nukes `MERGE_HEAD` (and I assume generally screws around with the git state, such that the merge cannot be resumed)

EDIT:

Manually "resetting" the files, by checking out `C` before hand and copying over the relevant files *works* but is quite slow and tedious due to the large and complex nature of the repositor.

*(lots of projects in separate folders, each with their own node_modules/packages folders that will tank the copy time, unless I target specific folders :( )*

I'm *hoping* for something automated. #optimism

Comment: What about just checking out C somewhere else and copying files over?

Comment: Yes, that's the manual intervention option I have, and am hoping to avoid, because there are dozens of these merges that I have to "teach".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem then. You can automate it in the same way as above steps - simply put the commands in a shell script and iterate over all the cases with some kind of loop...

Comment: Yes, that would certainly work. Or I could just run `dedicated-git-command-that-i-don't-know-about-to-tell-rerere-to-learn-the-contents-of-that-merge-commit` ... if it exists and SO can tell me about it.

Comment: That's why I didn't ask "how can I script this specific sequence of steps". You should know by now that SO *loves* to tell people that they have XY-Problems :)

Comment: Git includes a script, [`contrib/rerere-train.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/rerere-train.sh), that will help you out. You'll probably have to fuss with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In Git 2.36 and later, you can use [`git show --remerge-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---diff-mergesremerge) to create a diff showing how a merge was resolved. This can be used to do exactly what you want, with a few tricks.

1. First, we recreate the merge conflict, but with predictable conflict markers. Just after the failed `git merge B`, you can run:

   ```
   git checkout --merge :/
   ```

   This will recreate the merge conflict, but use `ours` and `theirs` on the merge conflict markers lines. The [top pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary.html#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-top) (`:/`) is used so this works from any directory in your repository.
2. Then we use `git show --remerge-diff`, pass its output to `sed` to also use `ours` and `theirs` as conflict markers, and finally apply this diff:

   ```
   git show --format= --remerge-diff C | \
   sed -e 's/<<<<<<< .*/<<<<<<< ours/g' -e 's/>>>>>>> .*/>>>>>>> theirs/g' | \
   git apply
   ```

Note that in contrast to rerere,  this approach allows you to also reapply any changes that were done in the merge outside of conflict regions.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but `reset --soft` changes your commit parent, not your index. You want

```
git worktree add scratch A  # or C^1
git -C scratch merge B      # or C^2
git -C scratch read-tree C
git -C scratch rerere
git worktree remove -f scratch
```

and you're done.  `git read-tree` has a ton of options, it's at the core of basically every index/worktree operation Git ever does, the one-tree version just loads the index, here replacing the inflight merge content pointers with the final merge result pointers.